# valgrind error with strcpy

Tags: c, linux, string, memory, valgrind

This code is supposed to extract a path from the userInput null-terminated string

```
  /* begin createPath */
    static inline char* createPath(char * userInput)
    {/* This function retuns the path from the userInput */
            int pathStringLength = 0;
            char *buf = userInput;
            while(*(buf++) != ' ')
                    pathStringLength++;
            char *path = malloc(pathStringLength+1);
            strncpy(path, userInput, pathStringLength);
    //      memcpy(path, userInput, pathStringLength);
            path[pathStringLength+1] = '\0';        
            return path;
    }
    /* end createPath */
```

According to valgrind, this code has an error:

```
> ==2919== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
> ==2919==    at 0x400A87: createPath (in /home/aral/learn/myShell/myShell)
> ==2919==    by 0x400A4C: parseInput (in /home/aral/learn/myShell/myShell)
> ==2919==    by 0x4009C3: main (in /home/aral/learn/myShell/myShell)
> ==2919== 
> ==2919== Invalid write of size 1
> ==2919==    at 0x400AC3: createPath (in /home/aral/learn/myShell/myShell)
> ==2919==    by 0x400A4C: parseInput (in /home/aral/learn/myShell/myShell)
> ==2919==    by 0x4009C3: main (in /home/aral/learn/myShell/myShell)
```

Searching on stackoverflow for similar problems, some people talked about adding a null-terminator while others mentioned using `memcpy` instead of `strcpy`; I am adding a null anyway and I tried to use `memcpy` but nothing improved, valgrind kept complaining.

What am I doing wrong here exactly? and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
path[pathStringLength+1] = '\0';
```

is wrong. That's one byte off the end. You mean:

```
path[pathStringLength] = '\0';
```

You will also have a buffer overrun if the input string does not have a space. Check for the null terminator in your loop and terminate when you encounter one. I'd write it like this:

```
while (*buf != ' ' && *buf != '\0')
{
    pathStringLength++;
    buff++;
}
```

For what it is worth, I think `memcpy` is probably a better option here. Once you've worked out exactly how much text needs to be copied, you may as well just blit it over. No need for a string function which looks for null terminators. You, once you fix the code, have already checked for them.

And you should check the return value of `malloc`.

Comment: I omitted the malloc checking just for clarity; as for the +1 I am kinda ashamed I missed that lol 
Thanks.

The invalid write error is gone; but what about the first error?

Comment: Why is memcpy better here, please?

Comment: As for the other error, I'm not sure. Did you fix all the errors I mentioned. The null terminator check too?

Comment: @AdelQodmani: `memcpy` is better because it will just copy the number of bytes requested.  Using `strcpy` or `strncpy` includes a check for null on each byte copied.  Since you've already figured out how many bytes you want to copy, there's no need to include another null check in during the copy.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan and tomlogic:
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

You write to `path[pathStringLength+1]` instead of `path[pathStringLength]` - the index are 0-based.

Answer (score 0):

`strncpy` is not safer method to use as `strcpy`. [man strncpy](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strncpy) says,

`The strncpy() function is similar, except that at most n bytes of src are copied. Warning: If there is no null byte among the first n bytes of src, the string placed in dest will not be null-terminated.`

So to protect this from not `NULL` terminating below practice helps,

```
strncpy(des, src, len)
des[len -1] = '\0';
```

Comment: How does this relate to the question that was asked?

Comment: `NULL` is defined as `((void *) 0)` and `des[len-1]` is `char`, so it should better be `des[len -1] = 0;` or `des[len -1] = '\0';`.